# User is not locked out after the logon time expires in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, parental-controls, mmc

I set up parental control on a user account and blocked it from logging in from 5 PM to 8 PM.

I ran **mmc.exe** and added a **snap-in**.

Then from **Administrative Templates --> Windows Components --> Windows logon --> set action to take when logon hours expire**, I selected to **lock the user when logon time expires**.

I logged in to that account at 4.50 PM and waited to see if it is working. But it is not working. I hid two drives in my system from that user using mmc.exe only and that's working fine. I can't see those two drives, but the locking of the user when the time expires is not working.

Comment: You logged into the limited account, correct?  What other options are there and have you configured all those options?

Comment: yeah. i configured some of the options. one cannot login to the  limited account from 5-8 PM. it's showing you are not permitted at this time. but if one logged in to it before 5 PM, the session is continued though the time crosses 5 PM.

Comment: This may be of interest to you: [Enforce user time restrictions to log out or off from Windows 7](http://superuser.com/a/357309/97028).

Comment: @CharlieRB i don't want to use extraa apps to achieve this. i can create a batch file and add that to start up to run **rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation** to lock that user after a specific time. i'm just wondering why it can't be done from Microsoft Management Console.