# How to setup login time limits (a.k.a. "parental controls") if you don't want to login with a Microsoft account?

Tags: windows-10, parental-controls

When creating accounts on Windows 10, you get a choice between "Your family" and "Other users".

If you choose "Your family" you are forced to use a Microsoft account to sign in. There are various reasons why one wouldn't want to do that, such as too much sharing of private information with Microsoft, etc.

If you choose "Other users" you can create regular accounts just fine. However, if you need to setup time limits for some accounts, it is impossible to do so. It is a feature exclusive to "Your family". Not all time-restricted users I want to create are my family, and not everyone is okay with sharing their info with Microsoft.

So, is there a way to setup login time limits for the "Other users" type of accounts?

Answer (score 16):

Setting logon hours using `net` command will only prevent users from logging in outside the allowed times, but will not lock their sessions or force log out when the logon hours expire.

To lock user session after logon hours expire, run the `Local Group Policy Editor` and set action to take when logon hours expire:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then type `gpedit.msc`.
2. Under `User Configuration` -> `Administrative Templates` -> `Windows Components` -> `Windows Logon Options`, click on `Set Action to take when logon hours expire`.
3. Choose `Enabled`, then set the action to `Lock` or `Logoff`, depending on your needs.

Comment: I believe there must be more to this process than described since I have now enabled user time limits and set the local policy as described and it did not logoff or lock after the time limit.

Comment: +1 this works for me! The user will get a 1 minute warning then be logged off, assuming you picked "Logoff". Command to set the times: "net user <USERNAME> /times:M-Su,12:00-22:00". Windows 10 home does not have gpedit.msc by default, had to dig for a way to add that.

Comment: In my case, "Windows Logon Options" don't have that option, 4 others, but not the one about logon expiration :( Any ideas why?

Comment: I installed gpedit.msc on Windows 10 Home, and "Windows Logon Options" was missing, so I editted the registry directly, you just need to be logged in as the user in question, then add: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System] "LogonHoursAction"=dword:00000003  (there are three options for this value: 1=Lock, 2=Disconnect, 3=Logoff)

Comment: This won't work with a Microsoft account, but it will with a local or domain account, it seems.

Comment: the approach with modifying registry (`LogonHoursAction`) doesn't work in modern Windows 10 21H1, though it used to work fine with 19H3

Comment: Another datapoint, this method (gpedit or registry) does not work with Windows 21H1

Comment: I confirm that modifying the policy with `gpedit` helps to lock the session when logon hours are over on Windows 10 Home N 21H1. PC reboot is needed after the change.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, the parental controls in Windows 10 cannot be used with local accounts. So I researched third party software that can limit time on Windows 10 with local accounts and found these:

[Time boss](http://nicekit.com/parental-control-software.htm)

[TimesUpKidz](http://www.timesupkidz.com/)

Time boss officially supports Windows 10 (at least they say so in their FAQ). Not sure about TimesUpKidz. They cost about $30-$50 but maybe a small price to avoid sharing private info with Microsoft?

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/184302/how-can-i-limit-the-usage-time-for-an-user-profile-in-windows) for more info.

Comment: Worked successfully on a local account for me, think it may be online accounts that differ.

Comment: @DanDevine affirmative. That's exactly the issue, it seems.

Answer (score -1):

The "net" command limits the logon hours, not limiting the usage time. Once user logged on during the allowed logon hours, Windows will not force the user to log off.

However, if a parent set a child account with time limit via Windows Parental Controls, the child will be forced to logoff after the time limit is up.

So, for the time being, there is no other way to set the time limit without Windows Parental Control. But, if you are bold, take a look at Windows Parental Controls API, and build your own app.

Comment: This worked in Windows 8 for quite some time, but stopped.