# Is it possible to create a windows 10 user who's account has a time restrictions?

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to find out if there is anyway to create a windows user account that has time restrictions set to it.  The problem I am having is I have multiple users that need to use this one computer but I want to restrict their use to only one hour.  What I would like to do is the log the person into the user account and after an hour the computer would automatically log the windows user out of the computer.

Comment: might start here: http://superuser.com/questions/950660/windows-10-how-to-setup-login-time-limits-a-k-a-parental-controls-if-you-d although, everything I read, has specific times. Not a time span the way you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting you can set for any user account with **time limits** (i.e. User1 can use the computer only from 5 PM to 6 PM every day) but that does not seem to be what you want. You want to make **usage limits**.

The easiest solution (without using any third-party software) will probably be to use the **Microsoft Family Features** that could be applied on a **Child Account.** But for that, you'd have to use Microsoft Accounts instead of Local Accounts (I don't know if that is a problem for you.)

See some information how and what you can set over **[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12439/microsoft-account-set-child-limits)**

> you can also set a maximum time per device that determines how many
>   hours per day they can use them. For example, you might let them spend
>   two hours a day on each device during the week, but give them more
>   time on weekends.

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially utilize the built-in `Task Scheduler` function to create a task to do something very close to that.

1. Open the `Task Scheduler` with admin privileges and create a task with an appropriate name and description, similar to this example:

[image: General Tab]

2. Configure the **Trigger** to be **At log on of any user**:

[image: Triggers Tab]

3. Configure the **Action** to be **Start a program**, navigate to `C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe`, and add the arguments `/l /t 3600`.

[image: Actions Tab]

This will automatically logoff the user after 3600 seconds, a.k.a. one hour.  If you ever need to override this yourself, you can execute the `shutdown /a` command to abort the timer.

Comment: But how would this prevent the user from logging in again?

Comment: @YisroelTech, it wouldn't.  It is an admittedly imperfect solution, but relatively simple (as well as no additional cost) compared to utilizing a full-sized Parental Controls software suite.