# Limit a user's usage time in Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, parental-controls

I want to limit the usage of a local user on a Windows 10 Pro machine.
I remember on Windows XP there was a UI thing that would allow me to just select the days and the time, when that time came the user would be logged off.

I can't seem to find that for Windows 10 Pro. I can see there are some net commands but those, I believe, won't log off the user if he exceeds the time.

Anyone know of how I can force a user to log off after a certain time like 10pm?

Comment: [How To Set Parental Controls for Windows 10 | Net Nanny](https://www.netnanny.com/blog/how-to-set-parental-controls-for-windows-10/) "Manage screen time, either via a schedule or a maximum number of hours."

Comment: @DavidPostill has basically answered your question. I remark that if you are not using a Microsoft account, see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/950660/windows-10-how-to-setup-login-time-limits-a-k-a-parental-controls-if-you-d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the user you are trying to limit, there are several built-in ways to handle this.

Since you mentioned Windows 10 Pro I'll give the ones that would work for any user first.
I found a good article on how to do this that includes command line options.
https://www.howtogeek.com/250224/how-to-set-time-limits-for-a-regular-account-in-windows-10/

Keep in mind that if the machine is on an administered network like a business or enterprise, these settings will likely be overridden by a group policy. Concurrently, if the machine is on an administered network, the easiest way is to limit the user's account on the domain controller so the same setting is applied no matter which computer they use. 
A good instruction video for that can be found at [this YouTube video.](https://youtu.be/rsEzw2mkMo0) Of course, the person adding the settings would need rights to do so.

If you are trying to limit it for a child, family member, etc, Microsoft Family Safety is a great tool. Just visit family.microsoft.com to set it up and administer it. Anytime you need to make changes, temporarily grant more time, etc, you just visit that same site.
Two caveats: 
To ensure it works as expected, 
(1) you need to keep the Windows operating system updated
(2) it's required for them to have a Microsoft account

To see more about establishing a Microsoft Family group and why you might want one, visit
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12413