# How to Prevent Disabling Programs on Startup (Windows)

Tags: windows-10, boot, task-manager

I am currently making a program to give my children time when opening a computer. So my children can only turn on the computer for 5 hours per day.

The program that I created has been entered into the startup program on Windows. But the problem is when my child deactivates the startup program that I created, the program cannot run when Windows is turned on.

Because to deactivate the program at startup is very easy, which is just by opening the task manager -> startup -> then disable the program I created.

Is there a way that the program that I made must run at startup? and can't possibly be turned off? Unless deleted.

Sorry my English is not very good, I hope you understand what I mean. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.
First, go into your control panel, and create a second user account for your children. Alter the privileges of this second account, so that it is NOT an administrative account.
Now, assuming your primary account IS an administrative account, you first want to make sure that your start up is now in a possibly new, but more importantly the correct location.  TO do this goto your start menu, then programs, then startup, right click startup and "Explore."  Do this a second time and click "Explore All Users."
My guess is your startup program is in the default, "Explore."  Move it to the folder that opened when you clicked "Explore all users."
Now it will run for you child's account too.
But we aren't done yet.  Now you want to right click on the program's shortcut, here in the startup folder.  Then goto this program's properties.
On the Compatibility tab, you want to check the "Privilege Level" checkbox, and have it "Run this program as an administrator."  Additionally, click the "Change settings for all users" button, and click the same checkbox here too.
Now to the "Shortcut" tab. Here you want to click the "Advanced" button, and again there is a "Run as administrator" checkbox.
Lastly, to the "Security" tab, then under Edit you should be able to ensure that your child's account ( you may have to click the add button, and add it here) has only Read & Execute, and Read checked.  You want to also, specifically Deny "Modify", "Write" and "Full Control."

I hope this helps!

P.S. I almost forgot, you will need to password protect your account (the administrative account) and not share your password with the kids.  Let them only get on the computer with a regular user account.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 you will find much better tools than any program you can write.

See the article
[How To Set Parental Controls for Windows 10](https://www.netnanny.com/blog/how-to-set-parental-controls-for-windows-10/).

If you are not using a Microsoft account, see the post
[Windows 10: how to setup login time limits (a.k.a. “parental controls”) if you don't want to login with a Microsoft account?](https://superuser.com/questions/950660/windows-10-how-to-setup-login-time-limits-a-k-a-parental-controls-if-you-d).