# Local account cannot start application (youth protection)

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, parental-controls

On my private Windows 10 Pro machine, I only use local accounts, no Microsoft accounts. I have, some time ago, created further local accounts for my family members, and all is well.

One Steam game I installed for one of those local accounts cannot be started; when I do so, I get the message "Parental Controls have prevent this application from running".

Similar to this question [How to setup login time limits (a.k.a. "parental controls") if you don't want to login with a Microsoft account?](https://superuser.com/questions/950660/how-to-setup-login-time-limits-a-k-a-parental-controls-if-you-dont-want-to) I have never linked any account on that machine to a Microsoft account. As the family/parental controls are only accessible if you do so, I am very sure that I have never activated those (and sure enough, if I try to enter them through Settings => Family..., I immediately get sent off to Microsoft's website/login screen).

I am familiar with regedit and gpedit... where could I go looking to see whether parental controls are actually enabled, and how to disable them locally?

EDIT: Added the actual english message, thanks to @Ramhound's comment.

Comment: "windows youth protection" - This perhaps a bad translation of the actual message. "windows youth protection" is not a thing, in any version of Windows, I suggest changing the language of the installation to English to determine the actual (English) message.  Are you sure every account on the machine is actually a local account?  I am pretty sure the actual message is "Parental Controls have prevent this applicaton from running" which means you actually do have Windows 10 parental controls enabled on the account in question.

Comment: @Ramhound, yes, this seems like the most probable translation. It does seem that I do have parental controls enabled, and the question is how I would disable them. The "official" way seems through the MS account, but there is none - not for myself (admin) and absolutely certainly not for the local child account in question (that one has no online presence whatsoever).